# Does the upcoming Merge to Proof of Stake reduce supply or tighten it?

Tags: mining, proof-of-stake, pow, the-merge

With the talked about merge to POS, what does this impact besides getting rid of POW miners?

Will emissions be the same % as POW?

How does the merge affect supply of coins?

Answer (score 0):

The merge (replacing PoW with PoS) reduces issuance of ETH by ~90%.

From https://ethereum.org/en/upgrades/merge/issuance August 22 2022:

> - Mining rewards ~13,000 ETH/day pre-merge
> - Staking rewards ~1,600 ETH/day pre-merge
> - **After The Merge, only the ~1,600 ETH per day will
>   remain, dropping total new ETH issuance by ~90%**
> - The burn: At an
>   average gas price of at least 16 gwei, at least 1,600 ETH is burned
>   every day, which effectively brings net ETH inflation to zero or less
>   post-merge.